# Unable to access jarfile? [Ubuntu, Linux]

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have been trying to solve this for a few days now but I just can't seem to grasp why this isn't working properly. I am trying to launch a jar file from ProcessBuilder but it just says that the jar file isn't found. If I run the exact same command from the terminal then it runs like a charm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The parameter s is the server file, I have already confirmed that the proper parameter is being passed down.

Here is a shortened version of the method (It errors on pb.start):

```
public static void startServer(String s){
    File server = new File(DataManager.getWorkingDirectory() + "/Servers/" + s + "/");
    if(server.exists()){
        if(serverProcess == null){
            try{
                String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                boolean isLinux = (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0) ? true : false;
                //java -jar -XX:MaxPermSize=126M -Xmx1G -jar ...(PathToJar)/server.jar
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "-XX:MaxPermSize=" + permSize + "M", "-Xmx" + ramAmount + "G", "\"" + (!isLinux ? DataManager.getWorkingDirectory().replace("\\", "/") : "") + "Servers/" + s + "/server.jar\"", "nogui");
                if(!isLinux){
                    pb.directory(server);
                }else{
                    pb.directory(new File(DataManager.getWorkingDirectory()));
                }
                logger.info("Starting Server...");
                final Process p = pb.start();
                GUIMain.serverProcess  = p;
```

Here is the entire method:

```
public static void startServer(String s){
    File server = new File(DataManager.getWorkingDirectory() + "/Servers/" + s + "/");
    if(server.exists()){
        if(serverProcess == null){
            try{
                String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                boolean isLinux = (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0) ? true : false;
                //java -jar -XX:MaxPermSize=126M -Xmx1G -jar ...(PathToJar)/server.jar
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "-XX:MaxPermSize=" + permSize + "M", "-Xmx" + ramAmount + "G", "\"" + (!isLinux ? DataManager.getWorkingDirectory().replace("\\", "/") : "") + "Servers/" + s + "/server.jar\"", "nogui");
                if(!isLinux){
                    pb.directory(server);
                }else{
                    pb.directory(new File(DataManager.getWorkingDirectory()));
                }
                logger.info("Starting Server...");
                final Process p = pb.start();
                GUIMain.serverProcess  = p;
                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    public void run(){
                        try{
                            if(serverList != null){
                                serverList.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                            String s = null;
                            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                                if(s.toUpperCase().contains("EULA")){
                                    updateTextPane("<font color=\"red\">" + s.replace("Go to eula.txt for more info.", "Please press the <font color=\"green\">Agree to EULA</font> button to agree to the EULA.") + "</font>");
                                    runCommand("stop");
                                }else{
                                    updateTextPane(s);
                                }
                            }
                            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                                updateTextPane(s);
                            }
                            try{
                                Field field = p.getClass().getDeclaredField("hasExited");
                                field.setAccessible(true);
                                while (!(boolean) field.get(p)) {}
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                CrashReport.logStackTrace(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
                                updateTextPane("<font color=\"red\">Server is offline.</font>");
                                GUIMain.serverProcess = null;
                                if(serverList != null){
                                    serverList.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            CrashReport.logStackTrace(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();
            }catch(Exception e1){
                CrashReport.logStackTrace(e1.getMessage(), e1.getStackTrace());
            }
        }else{
            updateTextPane("<font color=\"red\">Server is already running!</font>");
        }
    }else{
        logger.error("The server " + server.toString() + " doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the same command? Printout `processBuilder.command` and check it out.

Comment: Are you sure you are giving complete and correct path of  `jar` file?

Comment: What is error you are getting. Can u plz include stacktrace?

Comment: @KDM -- I have verified that I am using the exact same command.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I've tried giving the entire path starting at /home but I receive the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this happens because you quote the path when passing it to the `ProcessBuilder`:

```
"\"" + (!isLinux ? DataManager.getWorkingDirectory().replace("\\", "/") : "") + "Servers/" + s + "/server.jar\""
```

`ProcessBuilder` takes care of quoting arguments, so you end up with double quoting. Try the following instead:

```
(!isLinux ? DataManager.getWorkingDirectory().replace("\\", "/") : "") + "Servers/" + s + "/server.jar"
```

Another thing that looks suspicious is that relative path is used under Linux. This might be a problem as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix my issue either. As for the relative path thing, how would I go about fixing that?

I currently run the main program from folder "MSC", It is supposed to target "/MSC/Servers/s/server.jar".

Comment: There is easy way to diagnose it. From your app print (1) `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` and (2) path to the jar file you are constructing. Then from the terminal make sure that 1 + 2 gives you an existing file

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have command like below

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-XX:MaxPermSize=" + permSize + "M", "-Xmx" + ramAmount + "G", "\"" +  " -jar" + (!isLinux ? DataManager.getWorkingDirectory().replace("\\", "/") : "") + "Servers/" + s + "/server.jar\"", "nogui");
```

Comment: The quotes aren't the issue, none of the folders have have special characters or spaces in them.

Comment: This is not about qoutes. This is about keeping -XX:MaxPermSize like params before final -jar comand

Comment: My bad, I see it now. I have added the quotes and moved the -jar argument but nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: You need to remove quotes

Comment: There we go! Thank you both so much!